# How do I set a basedir in Jade using command line

Tags: command-line, pug, absolute-path

Is there a way to set 'basedir' option in jade command line? Or, maybe, another way to use absolute pathing there. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried running `jade --help`?

Comment: Yep. There are two options: -O and -p, but I don't understand how to use ones to set a basedir. Сan you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Jade has, among other options, the following

`-O, --obj <str|path>   JavaScript options object or JSON file containing it`

So you could write something like this:

`jade -O "{basedir:'/home/charlie/Git/ElfSite/Code'}" temp.jade`

Or you could create a file called **options.json** that looked something like this:

`{
    "basedir": "/home/charlie/Git/ElfSite/Code",
    "title": "My Title"
}`

And then call jade like this:

`jade -O options.json temp.jade`

Or like this:

`jade --obj options.json temp.jade`